# Center div at bottom without postion element?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header and the only way I can find out how to put my nav menu in the middle of my header is by making my header with the position of relative. Is there another way of doing this? Thanks. I've also tried to make the nav menu at the bottom of the header too. No success on that either..

http://jsfiddle.net/LR7zV/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="/img/logo.png">
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*-- HEADER --*/

#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#2C2E31;
    border-bottom:#242426 solid 2px;
}

img#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}

#nav li a {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

/*-- CONTENT --*/

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#2A2B2D;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/UgadU/)**

Comment: Well then, I didn't think it would want to work like that. I must've put it in the wrong place before... I still don't know how to get it on the bottom of the header.

Comment: I also suggest removing the (default) left padding from your `UL` with `padding:0px;`. It throws off the centering.